# Nest thermostat issue - only blows hot air if heat is on and fan is forced on. No air circulation with heat only

Tags: thermostat, heating, fans, nest

A few months ago I installed a nest thermostat and everything worked fine. I ended up giving that one away and installed another one A few days ago. It worked for one day and then it stopped heating. With some trial and error we have figured out that when we turn on the heat the boiler turns on however the fan does not turn on so no hot air comes through the vents. If we force the fan on while the heat is on then it works. The cooling works fine.

I have stranded wire, but the old thermostat worked totally fine. I also did not shut off the breaker this time around while installing, could this problem be a result of maybe something shorting out? Tomorrow I will try to reinstall the old thermostat to check this. But it's very frustrating because nest customer support won't help because I have stranded wire, even though i know the nest works with my system as my last device worked for months.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the Nest is set for a gas furnace or an electric/fan-coil heat system?

Comment: I had it set to gas. I live in a huge condo building and it's my understanding that we have gas furnaces. Although I'm not sure how to check. The fan runs on electricity obviously. Should I try switching the settings to see if it works. Will that damage anything?

Comment: It won't break anything -- in fact, it should fix your problem -- your system is clearly *hydronic* (with a boiler) instead of using a gas *furnace*, so any advice that talks about gas furnaces doesn't apply to you

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT! So even though I'm paying a gas bill for heating, my heating is technically electric? (I obviously don't know a lot about different types of heaters!)

Comment: Also i don't see any way to give you any credit for solving my problem! So if there is some way to give you credit or something please let me know!

Comment: Left a short answer for you.  If you want the long story, [here you go](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/124864/27099)

Comment: @Speedoflife1 "Hydronic" means "hot water". You may not have radiators in your condo, but the heat from the boiler (powered by gas) is brought to your condo via hot water, then air is heated by blowing it through a heat exchanger then into your living space. Also, if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that you should click the up arrow next to _all_ answers that helped you (if there is more than one), and click the check mark next to the one that helps _the most_.

Answer (score 2):

### Your fan coil thinks its an electric heater, not a gas furnace

The reason why you had trouble with the fan on your hydronic fan coil/air handler is because your thermostat was set to control it as if it were a gas furnace, which determines for itself when to run the blower, while your air handler instead requires a separate fan demand in order to run the fan, much like some electrically heated air handlers.  This is a fairly common problem for hydronic systems, as hydronic fan coils are not standardized in their behavior in this regard, and most advice for thermostat installation does not discuss the gas/electric or "fossil" setting on the thermostat in this context.